# Difference between x | y and y <(x) in bash?

Tags: bash, pipe

Is there a difference between `command1 | command2` and `command2 <(command1)`?

For example, `git diff | more` vs `more <(git diff)`

My understanding is that both take the stdout of `command2` and pipe it to the stdin of `command1`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main difference is that `<(`...`)`, called "process substitution", is translated by the shell into a filename that is passed as a regular argument to the command; it doesn't send anything to the command's standard input. This means that it can't be used directly with commands such as `tr` which don't take a filename argument:

```
$ tr a-z A-Z <(echo hello)
usage: tr [-Ccsu] string1 string2
       tr [-Ccu] -d string1
       tr [-Ccu] -s string1
       tr [-Ccu] -ds string1 string2
```

However, you can always put another `<` in front of the `<(`...`)` to turn it into an input redirection instead:

```
$ tr a-z A-Z < <(echo hello)
HELLO
```

And because it generates a filename, you can use process substitution with commands that take more than one file argument:

```
$ diff -u <(echo $'foo\nbar\nbaz') <(echo $'foo\nbaz\nzoo')
--- /dev/fd/63  2016-07-15 14:48:52.000000000 -0400
+++ /dev/fd/62  2016-07-15 14:48:52.000000000 -0400
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 foo
-bar
 baz
+zoo
```

The other significant difference is that a pipe creates subshells which can't have side effects in the parent environment:

```
 $ echo hello | read x
 $ echo $x
 # nothing - x is not set
```

But with process substitution, only the process inside the parentheses is in a subshell; the surrounding command can still have side effects:

```
 $ read x < <(echo hello)
 $ echo $x
 hello
```

Worth mentioning that you can also write into a process with `>(`...`)`, although there are fewer cases where that's useful:

```
$ echo hello > >(cat)
hello
```

Comment: Oh, that's really cool! Thank you for the response, that answers my question perfectly.

Answer (score -4):

`a | b` takes the `stdout` output from executable `a` and feeds it to executable `b` as b's `stdin`.

`a > b` takes the `stdout` from executable `a` and redirects/writes it out to file `b`.

`a < b` takes the contents of file `b` and redirects/inputs it to executable `a` as its `stdin`

In other words, `|` pipes output between programs, while `<` and `>` pipes files into/out of programs.

Your version with `()` runs an extra process, while accomplishing essentially the same thing.

Comment: No; the `<(…)` notation is not as you describe!  It generates a file name; to redirect from it, you need `< <(…)` — or `> >(…)` for output redirection.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but a < b is different from a <(b).  (http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution)